# MVC Core SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null only on confirmation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

When getting the callback to `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` the call to `SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` returns info just fine. The user then registers and the callback to `/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation` is called and `SignInManagerGetExternalLoginInfoAsync` now returns null. The data isn't staying around for some reason.

If I look at requests through Fiddler, I can see in the call to `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` that there is a cookie named `Identity.External`. When calling `/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation`, that cookie is no longer there. I think this is the problem, but I have no clue why. In between these two calls there is a call for the `/favicon.ico` file that returns a `302` causing a call to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ffavicon.ico`. Both those calls still have the `Identity.External` cookie showing.

This just started happening and I can't figure out why.